# "String or binary data would be truncated." for NVARCHAR but not VARCHAR in LIKE operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, nvarchar, varcharmax

In SQL Server, `nvarchar` takes twice the space of `varchar`, and its pre-page-pointer limit is 4000 compared to `varchar`'s 8000.

So, why does the following `like` comparison give a `String or binary data would be truncated.` error...

```
select 1 where '' like cast(replicate('x', 4001) as nvarchar(max))
```

...while casting as a massively larger `varchar` does not?

```
select 1 where '' like cast(replicate('x', 123456) as varchar(max))
```

In fact, why does the top live give a truncation error *at all* when it's clearly declared as `nvarchar(max)` which has a size limit of about 2GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of the `LIKE` operator:

> *pattern*
>
> Is the specific string of characters to search for in
>   match_expression, and can include the following valid wildcard
>   characters. *pattern* **can be a maximum of 8,000 bytes**.

This query shows a factual count of symbols:

```
select  len(replicate('x', 123456)) as  CntVarchar,
        len(replicate('x', 4001))   as  CntNVarchar


+------------+-------------+
| CntVarchar | CntNVarchar |
+------------+-------------+
|       8000 |        4001 |
+------------+-------------+
```

The first case has 8000 bytes. The second has 8002 bytes, that violates the rule "**can be a maximum of 8,000 bytes**".

Comment: As I said, the second line (with `123456`) does *not* receive a truncation error.

Comment: Because `replicate('x', 123456)` return `vachar(8000)` - not varchar(max) or varchar(123456).

Comment: select 1 where '' like cast(replicate(cast('x' as varchar(max)), 123456) as varchar(max)) --truncation error

Comment: @lptr https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 here described a behaviour of the REPLICATE function in such cases: "If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLICATE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to the appropriate large-value data type." So, in case replicate('x', 123456) it returns varchar(8000) in your case it returns varchar(max).

Comment: @Максим Золотенко , true, the comment was added as a clarification to the question of Devin Burke (...(with 123456) does not receive a truncation error.).